# Data don't exactly result when import - acumatica api

Tags: php, erp, acumatica

[link image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3tpj.png)

I import datarows to acumatica erp

with "**Business Account: TEST20**" and "**Business Account Name: cci**".

When I view it, result like image. My row data insert to record "**Business Account: AFA001**"

"**Business Account: AFA001**" is auto generate. (I don't know reson)

Who can you explain for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Business Account ID is set to auto generate. If that is the case then Acumatica will ignore any accountIDs you pass when creating a new customer.

If you want to change this you need to turn Auto Number off in your segmented keys setup.

Comment: Thank you very much @BRenfro. I try it, it is true which you say.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you need an assistance you have to provide your code here otherwise nobody can help you.
I've no idea what is going on your side because i do not know which screen do you use.
My opinion that you have to use common CR.XX.XX.XX screen to import Business Account